# Client and host machine on different networks

Tags: networking, vmware

I have configured several virtual networks on my Windows host machine with Virtual Network Editor. Trying to use host-only configuration with subnet 192.168.43.0 and mask 255.255.255.0 on VMnet0.

As result I got following configuration on host machine:

```
Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet0:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix . :

Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::bcb9:3631:470d:8438%23

Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.132.56

Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0

Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

Client Linux machine got following IP address:

```
192.168.43.128 with mask 255.255.255.0
```

I can't ping client Linux machine from Windows host machine.

Why both of these machines not on the same network? How to fix that ?

Comment: Your autoconfigured IP address is link-local, and not in the `192.168.43.*/24` subnet. So assign a proper IP address in the subnet range to it (google how to do that).

Comment: It is usually not a good idea to change VMnet0, VMnet1 or VMnet8. Use any other adapter to setup custom Networks. You can try what dirkt suggested or restore configuration for Vmnet0 back to default.